# Issue trying to connect a delete button

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to connect a button to the backend and I'm going wrong somewhere, I need some advice so I can get over this hump.

In the action file my deleteAccount function isnt moving into the first return. It will output reached confirm in console and that's it. Im lost as to why it won't continue but I know its something fundamental that Im missing. Any advice is appreciated

action file

```
export const deletingAccount = () => {
  return {
    type: DELETING_ACCOUNT
  };
};

export const accountDeletedSuccess = () => {
  return {
    type: ACCOUNT_DELETED_SUCCESS,
  };
};

export const accountDeleteFail = err => {
  return {
    type: ACCOUNT_DELETE_FAIL,
    payload: {err}
  };
};


export const deleteAccount = uuid => {
  if(window.confirm('Are you sure? This can NOT be undone!')) {
    console.log('reached confirm')
    return async dispatch => {
      console.log('reached dispatch')
      dispatch(deletingAccount());
      setAuthHeaders(axios);
      await axios.delete(`${ROOT_API_URL}/api/user/removeUser/${uuid}`)
      .then(data => {
        if (data.status === 200) {
          return dispatch(accountDeletedSuccess());
        }
        return dispatch(accountDeleteFail());
      })
      .catch(err => accountDeleteFail(err));
    }
  }
};
```

file with button

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="user-edit-profile-content">
        <h2 className="edit-profile-title">
          Account
        </h2>
        <div>
            <h4> 
                Delete all posts
            </h4>
            <h5>Delete everything you posted in the marketplace and services.</h5>
            <button className="user-profile-edit-button btn-white" onClick={this.editPageClick}>
              Delete
            </button>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div>
            <h4> 
                Delete account
            </h4>
            <h5>Delete account. This action cannot be undone.</h5>
            <button className="user-profile-edit-button btn-white" onClick={() => deleteAccount()}>
              Delete
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AccountSettingsContainer.propTypes = {
    deleteAccount: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      user: state.user.user,
    }
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {...Actions, deleteAccount })(AccountSettingsContainer));
```

Comment: Is this a frontend (browser code) question?

Comment: What is at `${ROOT_API_URL}/api/user/removeUser/` ?

Comment: Yes this is all front end code.
${ROOT_API_URL}/api/user/removeUser/ is 


`router.route('/removeUser')`
` `
    `.delete((req, res) => {`
` `
     `let currentUser = req.user.dataValues;`
` `
      `return service.removeUser(currentUser.uuid).then(removed => {`
` `
        `res.json(removed);`
` `
      `})`
` `
   `})`

I can't figure out how to format a comment, every ` ` is a new line. This comment is embarrassing I'm sorry